# Extract html cell data with BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this simple html table that has been extracted via requests from a website:

```
<tr align="center" class="tableRow1Font" >
<td>OPEN</td>
<td>80002</td>
<td>
<span style="font-weight:bold;">
ACCY
</span> 
<A HREF="http://bulletin.gwu.edu/search/?P=ACCY+2001" target="_blank">
<span style="font-weight:bold;">
2001
</span>
</A>
</td>

<td>10</td>
<td>Intro Financial Accounting</td>
<td>3.00</td>
<td> Ray, K</td>
<td><a href="http://virtualtour.gwu.edu/#MON" target="_blank" >MON</a> 113</td>
<td>MW<br>12:45PM - 02:00PM</td>
<td>08/25/14 - 12/06/14</td>
<td>

</td>
</tr>
```

I have setup the extraction in python like this:

```
import bs4
import requests 

response = requests.get('http://my.gwu.edu/mod/pws/courses.cfm?campId=1&termId=201501&subjId=ACCY')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
```

Using Beautiful Soup how would I extract all the 'td' titles out of this table and separate them with a comma?

I want the extracted data to look like this:

```
OPEN, 80002, ACCY 2001, 10, Intro to Financial Accounting, 3.00, Ray, K, MW 12:45-02:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started. There is still a lot of extraneous whitespace from the html page that needs to be cleaned out of the results.

```
import bs4
import requests 

response = requests.get('http://my.gwu.edu/mod/pws/courses.cfm?campId=1&termId=201501&subjId=ACCY')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)  

for tr in soup.findAll('tr')[11:]:
    stack = []
    for td in tr.findAll('td'):
        stack.append(td.text.strip())
    print(",".join(stack))
```

Note that this ignores the first 11 tr's on the page, because they seemed to have unrelated information.

You will also need to find a better way to hold the data than by simply separating it with commas - otherwise, any commas in the course description could throw off whatever code you have trying to read the data back. Its probably better to work with a CSV library than to just join the data with commas manually.